# is there any class for use of sessions in package com.sun.net.httpserver?

Tags: java, http

in this package of java:

```
com.sun.net.httpserver
```

I didn't find any class that works with http sessions, how can I handle sessions if I'am using HttpServer and HttpExchange?

Answer (score 1):

This simple HTTP server is not related to Java EE. Insofar there is no concept of a Java EE like web session. You can either implement a session like behaviour on your own or upgrade to a real Java EE servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty. Both can run embedded in your own application or you can run Tomcat or Jetty stand alone and deploy your web application to it.